# Renew a web hosting certificate on IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I have a site published in IIS. The site using HTTPS protocol and the web hosting certificate is already expired. This web hosting certificate path is under the trust root certificate which is not expired yet. I am very new to this so I am not sure how to do since the certificate is created by the previous programmer. Can anyone help giving any idea on how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of renewing SSL/TLS on IIS can be divided into three parts: CSR generation, SSL renewal, and Installing the new SSL certificate.

**Generate an SSL Certificate Renewal CSR in Microsoft IIS:**

1. First, go to Start > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. In the left pane named Connections, click on your server’s hostname.
3. In the middle pane, you should see various options for your server. Double-click on the Server Certificates icon.
4. In the right pane named Actions, click on Create Certificate Request…
5. Now you’ll be asked information to generate a new CSR (Including these fields: Common Name, Organization, Organizational unit, City/locality, State/province, Country/region).
6. Select Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider as a Cryptographic service provider and 2048 as Bit Length.
7. Click Next. Specify your convenient location to store your newly generated CSR and click Finish.

**Certificate Renewal On Windows Server:**

The SSL renewal process isn’t the same for everyone, as it depends on where you purchased your SSL certificate from. You need to log into your account (of the platform where you purchased your SSL) and submit a renewal request by pasting your new CSR. Once the certificate authority (CA) has received your renewal request, it will conduct a verification process. Once the vetting process is over, the CA will issue the new (renewed) SSL certificate to you. You’re supposed to install this certificate on your IIS server.

**Install Your Renewed SSL Certificate on IIS Server:**

1. First, save the certificate to the same server from where you had generated your CSR.
2. Open your IIS Manager.
3. In the left pane named Connections, click on your server’s hostname.
4. In the middle pane, double-click on the Server Certificates icon.
5. In the right pane named Actions, click on Complete Certificate Request…
6. Click on the three dots (…) to browse to the .CER certificate file of your renewed SSL certificate.
7. Now give the certificate a friendly name that will be easy for you to refer to in the future and click OK.
8. Under the Connections pane, expand your server’s computer name, and then click the website that you want to enable SSL on.
9. Go to the Actions menu and click on Bindings.
10. In the Site Bindings pop-up, select https and click on Edit…
11. Now in the Add Site Binding pop-up, choose your renewed SSL (its friendly name) and click OK.

You could read the following article for a reference: [Microsoft IIS 10: Renew Your SSL Certificate](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-certificate-renewal-iis-10.htm)

Comment: I used windows manager to approve the CSR. It worked fine on the server. But on another PC, it said the certificate is not trusted by my computer. Do I need to use another CA to approve the CSR?

Comment: You can do this by exporting the root CA certificate from the server where you approved the CSR, and then importing it into another PC's Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. If that doesn't solve the problem, you need use a different CA to issue the certificate, you can choose a CA that both the server and other PCs trust, such as a well-known commercial CA or a public CA like Let's Encrypt.